# Most efficient way to calculation permutation P(n,r) where n can be a large integer

Tags: algorithm, permutation

If n can be as large as 1M and r something like 100, then what is the most efficient way to calculate nPr.

Answer (score 1):

```
P(n,r) = n! / (n-r)!
```

We easily can remove (n-r)! from nominator and denominator. Now formula is

```
P(n,r) = n*(n-1)*..(n-r+1)
```

.

.

.

**Old answer**, not for this question, about combinations:

```
C(n,k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)
```

We easily can remove (n-k)! from nominator and denominator. Now formula is

```
C(n,k) = n*(n-1)*..(n-k+1) / k! = n*(n-1)*..(n-k+1) / (1 * 2 * ...*k)
```

If we first calculate full nominator, it will very big.

But we can alternate steps - take n, then divide by the first term of denominator (1), multiplication by (n-1) - division by the second denominator term (2) and so on.

```
 C(n,k) = n / 1 * (n-1) / 2 * (n-2) / 3 .. * (n-k+1) / k
```

Note that partial nominator product always i divisible by partial denominator product of the same length.

With this approach intermediate result is not very big, and calculations with big numbers (long arithmetics) will be faster.

Comment: But the question is for permutation, not combination.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Bu permutation is P(n), it doesn't involve the second parameter (123 132 213 231 312 321). So what do you mean?

Comment: I caught. You want a number of **ordered** subsets. Edited.

Comment: Do you really need all of the permutations, or are you trying to grab them for some type of Monte Carlo simulation, or other technique that needs a large sample of all possible permutations?  Either way, I've had decent luck with the 'permute' package for these types of operations.  'Combinat' is another option, though I don't believe it has as much flexibility when it comes to restricting permutations.